# How to change Device Identifiers like Vendor or Model Name in Genymotion VM?

Tags: android, virtualization, genymotion

I want to change genymotion device identifiers to show my phone as a real one. What should i do and which file that i need to modify?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the build.prop file. Try this: https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001338045-Use-a-modified-build-prop-file-to-change-the-device-ID-manufacturer-model-etc-